# How do I ensure complete blockage of Anydesk or other remote access?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access

One of my colleagues wanted to show something on his desktop and asked me to install Anydesk so that he can share his ID with me. I used the portable version of Anydesk without installing. However I'm aware that he also got to know my Anydesk ID when he connected with me. I later deleted the portable installer. But I have following questions:

1. Can someone access my computer with the ID even if I don't have Anydesk on my computer? If yes, what can I do to stop that?
2. How do I ensure that my computer stays completely free from any remote access?

I don't plan to use Anydesk in future. So purging is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone access my computer with the ID even if I don't have Anydesk on my computer?

If you have removed the Anydesk executable then your computer cannot be accessed by that identification number.  Furthermore, to my knowledge, that identification number could not have been used after you closed the application. If Anydesk works anything like Teamviewer, there is either an option to generate a unique number, or there is at lest an option to generate a new client identification number.

> How do I ensure that my computer stays completely free from any remote access?

With regards to Anydesk specifically, uninstalling the application, is enough to prevent remote access to your system.  This of course assumes your colleague didn't upload anything to your computer without your knowledge.  **There is a reason programs like Anydesk are used by criminals that pretend to offer technical support.**

Comment: I see. I don't think anything else was installed in my computer. I could see his desktop and it was like screensharing. Didn't really need Anydesk for that. I also use a standard account in windows for work purpose, not admin account. But I will check if any unknown software is there. I didn't find any way to change that unique ID though. I didn't know these softwares are infamous.

Comment: @Bluebug - If the software isn't running then trying to connect to that same unique ID will result in an error.